# What 's the meaning of Web Pages 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I read some small articles about Visual studio 2012 and the new features.

But I'm really confused about this concept :

`Web Pages 2`

I want to know what does it mean and why this bad name ?

For [Example](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/whats-new/top-features-in-web-pages-2#mobile) .

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started .. and close

Comment: ever hear of [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/MVC)? how about [ASP.NET WebForms](http://www.asp.net/WebForms)? soo... now there's [ASP.NET Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ASP.NET Web pages, known officially as Web Forms, are the main
>   building block for application development. Web forms are contained
>   in files with a ".aspx" extension; these files typically contain
>   static (X)HTML markup, as well as markup defining server-side Web
>   Controls and User Controls where the developers place all the rc
>   content for the Web page. Additionally, dynamic code which runs on the
>   server can be placed in a page within a block <% -- dynamic code --
>   %>, which is similar to other Web development technologies such as
>   PHP, JSP, and ASP. With ASP.NET Framework 2.0, Microsoft introduced a
>   new code-behind model which allows static text to remain on the .aspx
>   page, while dynamic code remains in an .aspx.vb or .aspx.cs or
>   .aspx.fs file (depending on the programming language used).

The number refers to the Version.

Read [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET)